# Resolve Controller Path in Javascript File

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I'm using a Kendo grid to display results from a webservice. The webservice is accessed in a controller and then we point the Kendo grid dataSource to the controller like so:

**JavaScript**

```
var servicePath = "/Home/Search";
var postData = { "searchTerm" : searchTerm, "targetDB" : targetDB }

var grid = $("#grid1").kendoGrid({
    pageable: {
        pageSize: 10
    },
    dataSource: {
        error: function (e) {
            if (e.errors !== false) {
                $("#errorContainer").html(e.errors);
            }
        },
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: servicePath,
                dataType: "json",
                data: postData,
                type: "POST"
            }
        },
    },
    dataBound: function (e) {
        //Do Stuff
    }
});
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(string searchTerm, string targetDB)
{
    //Do Search and Return JSON
}
```

**Problem**

This works wonderfully when my URL is `http://localhost/Home/Index` but fails whenever it's something else, such as `http://localhost/` (default when project is run from root). I've experienced the same problems using a jQuery .ajax call as the kendo grid service call.

**Question**

So my question is, how can I put in the correct service URL for the Kendo Grid (or in general when pointing to a controller) and know it will work in all path variations?

I've tried using variations of `location.host` to get the full URL regardless then append the controller and method, but the Kendo service call fails with no error.

I imagine I should be able to parse the url and use what I need, but I've found that when I am at the root of the webpage I can't figure out what to put to make an ajax call work. I've tried using the controller/method and the entire url? I've also tried various techniques described below.

What am I missing? Is there a convention or technique I could use instead?

**Edit**

I also tried putting a hidden field on the page with a value of the controller URL:

```
<input type="hidden" value="@Url.Action("Search", "Home"); " id="serviceURL" />
```

And then using that value in the JS:

```
var servicePath = $("#serviceURL").val();
```

But I found that the value of `@Url.Action()` (Value : `Home/Search`) is the same whether your url is `http://localhost/` or `http:localhost/Home/Index`, so no luck. This still does not work when you're on the root page where the url looks something like "localhost/".

Thanks!

Comment: Use from var servicePath = @Url.Action("Search","Home")

Comment: Tried that, external JS files do not recognize the @ symbol.

Comment: your external JS can get parameter and you send the url as parameter to your function from cshtml ,....

Comment: @M.Azad I tried that as well. It ends up being the same value as the location.host, edited to show how that worked.